# How to avoid a racing condition from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to display a message that reads "Welcome, FirstName". I'm getting the first name from a firestore collection called 'useraccounts'.

Here's the related code:

```
import { doc, getDoc, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import {auth} from '../firebase';

const Main = () => {
   const db = getFirestore()
   const [user, setUser] = useState("");

   // getting the logged-in user 
   const currentUser = auth.currentUser;

const getUser = async () => {
  
  let userEmail = currentUser.email
  
  //undefined on first load or browser reload, but fine when I reload the code 
  console.log("userEmail: ", userEmail); 

  // the firestore bits
  const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userEmail)
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

  // checking to see if the user logged in has a user account record 
  // in the 'useraccounts' collection
  if (docSnap.exists()){
    setUser(docSnap.data().first);
  } else {
    //this doesn't show when it's undefined either by the way
    console.log("nothing here"); 
  }      
}

// calling it on load and reload...or so I thought
useEffect(() => {       
   getUser();
},[])
```

The problem? - It doesn't show me the name on load/refresh. But if I change some arbitrary stuff in the code to force a refresh, it shows. Thus, showing symptoms of a racing condition.

Placing the getUser() inside the useEffect does nothing different

Comment: What is the value of `currentUser` on first load?  Please edit the question to be clear.  I assume you are using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: yes, it shows the loggedin user email, uid, and so forth. No first name of course because Firebase doesn't have that available in their auth. I collect that in the login form and send it to the useraccounts collection that I am trying to call

Comment: can you try to do:
`useEffect(() => {       
   getUser();
},[user])`

also can you try to put this snippet inside the main function ?

Comment: @RenaudReguieg I tried that before. No effect.

Comment: I assume all promises are awaited ? 
also, I don't know how react perform (regarding useEffect) when the function has no JSX return value
Could you explain how is this function used ?

Comment: I don't understand - your comment says that on first load `currentUser` "shows the loggedin user email, uid, and so forth", but the comment in your code says that `userEmail` is undefined, which means the currentUser doesn't have email as you just said.  Please edit the question to more clearly illustrate what you're observing when this code runs, both first load and subsequent renders.  Ideally show what your log statements are and the contents of the log so we can play along.

Comment: Keep in mind that the currentUser is going to be null when the page initially loads and renders your components the first time.  Firebase Auth will take some time to validate the current user, then issue a callback when the user object is known.  You need to use an auth state observer to know when this happens, as Frank shows in his answer.  This isn't a "race", this is just the work that needs to be done to validate the user object when the page first loads from scratch.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't understand it either. Console-loggin the currentUser from auth returns the Object will that auth props including the email, uid, token, and all the other stuff. But, when I set the user to a new state, it is undefined on load/refresh. It only sets it after I do some change in the code, like adding a space somewhere and hit CMD+S

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah that was my suspicion too. But I'm not sure how to do that. I figured that I had to wait until the info was available some how

Comment: As I said, use an auth state observer as Frank shows in his answer. Also [read the documentation about that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data).

Comment: @DougStevenson See my comment on Frank's solution

Comment: If you have updated code that uses an auth state observer, and it's not working the way you expect, then you likely have an entirely new question to post along with your debugging details on that new code.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm not disagreeing, but `Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.` <- this is an error from bad syntax on the useEffect, no? That's what I'm getting from his code

Comment: @DougStevenson I made a new question with the solution below and showing the errors, as suggested. Though it will be closed as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `auth.currentUser` isn't set yet when the `Main` component is initialized, as determining the `currentUser` is an asynchronous operation (as Firebase needs to check with the server, a.o. whether the account has been disabled).

To solve this, use an auth state listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Based on that:

```
const Main = () => {
  const db = getFirestore()
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(); //  New state variable

  //  New useEffect listener
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
  }, []);;

  //  Cleaned this up a bit
  useEffect(() => {       
    let userEmail = currentUser.email; //  use the new currentUser state
  
    // the firestore bits
    const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userEmail)
    getDoc(docRef).then((docSnap) => {
      if (docSnap.exists()){
        setUser(docSnap.data().first);
      } else {
        console.log("nothing here"); 
      }      
    });
  }, [currentUser]); //  Re-run this effect when the currentUser changes
})
```

---

What OP ended up using:

```
//  New useEffect listener
useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    console.log("the user from the onAuth func: ", user.email);
    setCurrentUser(user);
  });
}, []);

//  Cleaned this up a bit
useEffect(() => {       
  let userEmail = currentUser.email; //  use the new currentUser state

  //This isn't reached. Not console logging 
  console.log("the currentUser from outside onAuth func: ", userEmail);

  // the firestore bits
  const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userEmail)
  getDoc(docRef).then((docSnap) => {
    if (docSnap.exists()){
      setUser(docSnap.data().first);
    } else {
      console.log("nothing here"); 
    }      
  });
}, [currentUser]); //  Re-run this effect when the currentUser changes
```

Comment: So, this gave me some issues. 1- Is that useEffect supposed to be async? or is it a typo? There's no await inside and it throw up a lot of bad mean red letters lol. Also, I console logged the 'user' from inside the onAuthStateChanged function and I did get the user, but the console log for currentUser <-- the new one, came back undefined. The setter inside the onAuthStateChanged is not mutating the state

Comment: 1. Good point. Removed the `async` marker. 2. If the auth state listener doesn't fire with a user, then no user is signed in. If that is unexpected, you'll want to show/debug when the user signs in (as that doesn't happen in the code you shared).

Comment: I made an edit to the question. I replaced the my code verbatim from yours. Notice the comments I am console-logging. I'm able to verify there is a user logged in, but it's not available outside of the onAuthState func.

Comment: I got it to work by putting everything inside onAuthStateChange even though it throws a react-native warning. But that's another issue. Can you adjust the answer to show one useEffect with the onAuthState and everything else in it? That way I can credit you. I wouldn't want future users to get the wrong code

Comment: I added the code from your question. Please remove it from there, as solutions should be posted in answers - not in questions. In the future, please edit the answer if you think it can be improved.

Comment: by the way, this was the completed solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78108974/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-cannot-read-property-email-of-undefined

Comment: I posted the question with the react-native error and this was the final fix which included your solution and a modification. currentUser is not needed because user is available inside the onAuthStateCHanged func the whole time. Maybe that shoudl be noted here. And then I can delete the other question