# Possible unhandled promise rejection. Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have this weird warning from react native complaining that the email is undefined. But it isn't. If it was, I wouldn't be able to log in or show the user's name that I am fetching in the function below. My guess is that for brief moment of time, the user.email is not reachable yet, and it triggers the warning. Same happens after I log out of the app (which makes sense). I generally would like to subscribe and unsubscribe to this function only when I am in this page and when the user object is available.

[image]

```
const db = getFirestore()
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(user);
const [user, setUser] = useState("");

const getUser = () => {
    
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    let userEmail = currentUser.email; 
  
    const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userEmail)
    await getDoc(docRef)
    .then((docSnap) => {
      if (docSnap.exists()){
        setUser(docSnap.data().first);
      } else {
        console.log("nothing here"); 
      }      
    });
  }); 
}

useEffect(() => {   
  getUser();
}, [currentUser]);
```

Comment: In your code , you are calling `setCurrentUser` method which is updating state and just after that you are trying to access latest state object and it's value which is not good as updating state is async process .. so just replace `currentUser.email` with `user.email` and make sure `user` object is not null or undefined

Comment: Fundamentally, as [jayesh said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78108974/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-cannot-read-property-email-of-undefined#comment137703108_78108974), `setCurrentUser` [is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately), it won't (and can't) change the `currentUser` constant (it's a constant, after all).  Just change `let userEmail = currentUser.email;` to `let userEmail = user.email;`, if you want the `email` property of the `user` parameter you're passing to `setCurrentUser`.

Comment: The code you've shown won't run at all, so it can't be the code you're actually using (or you're transpiling to ES5 and your transpiler isn't warning you of the problem). You can't access `user` in `const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(user);` above where `user` is defined via `const` in `const [user, setUser] = useState("");`, you'll get a ReferenceError since `user` will be in the [TMZ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz).

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani Splendid!!! Put a solution in . That did it. And while you are at it, mention that any reference to the currentUser and its setter is not necessary (for future visitors). Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code , you are calling setCurrentUser method which is updating state and just after that you are trying to access latest state object and it's value which is not good as updating state is async process .. so just replace

```
currentUser.email
```

with

```
user.email
```

in `onAuthStateChanged` method and make sure user object is not null or undefined

Note :- As per your current code , it looks you don't need `setCurrentUser` as you are already receiving `user` object